# Magento : After Change topmenu.phtml File 2columns-left.phtml Not Work

Tags: magento-1.9, category, menu

I set mega menu using `topmenu.phtml` file but when I go to category page then `2columns-left.phtml` file not working properly. so can any one help me?

I am using `magento ver:1.9`

Comment: Which error you are facing on category page?

Comment: <div class="col-left sidebar" style="display: none;">  <div class="col-main" style="width: 100%;">  these class add automatically. so can you please help me..